# Moving mesh in object mode, armature is not moving, mesh stretches

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

im trying to do a robot walking animation, i already did a walking cycle im quite satisfied with, but when i try to move the robot in object mode, the armature does not move and the robot stretches. Anyone know where could be the problem?

Here is the blend file : https://en.webshare.cz/#/file/ZuNNgzrKUF/anim-2-blend

[image]
[image: Armature move]

Comment: the object is parented to the armature, so if you move it away, it will deform; If you want to move the robot, move its armature

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i added the image when i try to move the armature, it does the same thing, the problem is probably that the mesh and armature are not moving together at the same speed.

Comment: it works fine with the file you've shared

Comment: Thats weird, i just tried it on another computer with the same result, both blender 2.9. I just select the armature in object mode and move using G on Y axis, but got the result from the second image.

Comment: Deactivate the Proportional Editing, but I'm still missing something here...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, turning off the proportional editing solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by proportional editing feature in blender.

Comment: Ok, but what did you do about it? Add some details.